# Decryption using OpenSSL

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

I am trying to implement encryption and decryption in a client server model using OpenSSL. I am encrypting an array of bytes (it is a key to be used in further decryption) using already established key in variable "skey". Following is the server side of the code

```
// Generate an initialization vector (IV) for CBC mode
    const EVP_CIPHER* cipher = EVP_aes_256_cbc(); // Use the desired cipher algorithm
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx_encrypt = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    const unsigned char* plaintext = sessionKey;
    size_t plaintext_len = sessionKeyLen;
    const int MAX_TEXT_LENGTH = 256;
    unsigned char iv[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];
    
    if (RAND_bytes(iv, EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error generating IV\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Set the IV for the encryption operation
    if (EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx_encrypt, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, skey, iv) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting encryption IV\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Encrypt the plaintext (session key)
    unsigned char ciphertext[MAX_TEXT_LENGTH + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH];
    int ciphertext_len;

    if (EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx_encrypt, ciphertext, &ciphertext_len, plaintext, plaintext_len) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error encrypting data\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Finalize the encryption
    int final_len;
    if (EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx_encrypt, ciphertext + ciphertext_len, &final_len) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error finalizing encryption\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    ciphertext_len += final_len;

    const size_t ivLength = EVP_CIPHER_iv_length(EVP_aes_256_cbc()); // Get the length of the IV
    const size_t concatenatedMessageLength = ivLength + ciphertext_len;
    unsigned char concatenatedMessage[concatenatedMessageLength];

    memcpy(concatenatedMessage, iv, ivLength);
    memcpy(concatenatedMessage + ivLength, ciphertext, ciphertext_len);

    printf("Concatenated Message 1:\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < concatenatedMessageLength; i++) {
        printf("%02x", concatenatedMessage[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx_encrypt);


    // Preparing for Bob's share

    // Generate an initialization vector (IV) for CBC mode
    plaintext = (const unsigned char*)"Verification Message SessionKey";
    plaintext_len = strlen((const char*)plaintext);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx_encrypt2 = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();

    if (RAND_bytes(iv, EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error generating IV\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Set the IV for the encryption operation
    if (EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx_encrypt2, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, sessionKey, iv) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting encryption IV\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Encrypt the plaintext (Bob's share)
    if (EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx_encrypt2, ciphertext, &ciphertext_len, plaintext, plaintext_len) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error encrypting data\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Finalize the encryption
    if (EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx_encrypt2, ciphertext + ciphertext_len, &final_len) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error finalizing encryption\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    ciphertext_len += final_len;
    const size_t concatenatedMessageLength2 = ivLength + ciphertext_len;
    unsigned char concatenatedMessage2[concatenatedMessageLength2];

    memcpy(concatenatedMessage2, iv, ivLength);
    memcpy(concatenatedMessage2 + ivLength, ciphertext, ciphertext_len);

    printf("Concatenated Message 2:\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < concatenatedMessageLength2; i++) {
        printf("%02x", concatenatedMessage2[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx_encrypt2);

    // Sending Server Share and Verification Message
    if (concatenatedMessageLength > 0) {
        send(client_sock_Bob, concatenatedMessage, concatenatedMessageLength, 0);
        // Send the encrypted hash to the server
        usleep(100);
        if (concatenatedMessageLength2 > 0) {
            send(client_sock_Bob, concatenatedMessage2, concatenatedMessageLength2, 0);
        } else {
            printf("Server Verification message is Null: %s\n");
        }
    } else {
        printf("Session key is Null : %s\n");
    }
```

this snippet encrypts and send 2 messages. Firstly, it is encrypting a session key using already established skey. Secondly, it is encrypting a verification message using the session key.
Client's code is as follows.

```
// Receive concatenatedMessage2
    char receivedMessage1[4096];
    ssize_t concatenatedMessageLength1 = recv(sock, receivedMessage1, sizeof(receivedMessage1), 0);
    if (concatenatedMessageLength1 > 0) {
    memcpy(concatenatedMessage1, receivedMessage1, concatenatedMessageLength1);
    } else if (concatenatedMessageLength1 == 0) {
    // Connection closed by the server
    fprintf(stderr, "Connection closed by the server.\n");
    exit(1);
    } else {
    // Error receiving data
    fprintf(stderr, "Error receiving concatenatedMessage2.\n");
    exit(1);
    }


    // Receive concatenatedMessage1
    char receivedMessage2[4096];
    ssize_t concatenatedMessageLength2 = recv(sock, receivedMessage2, sizeof(receivedMessage2), 0);
    if (concatenatedMessageLength2 > 0) {
    memcpy(concatenatedMessage2, receivedMessage2, concatenatedMessageLength2);
    } else if (concatenatedMessageLength2 == 0) {
    // Connection closed by the server
    fprintf(stderr, "Connection closed by the server.\n");
    exit(1);
    } else {
    // Error receiving data
    fprintf(stderr, "Error receiving concatenatedMessage1.\n");
    exit(1);
    }

    bzero(buffer, 1024);

    const EVP_CIPHER* cipher = EVP_aes_256_cbc(); // Use the desired cipher algorithm
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx_decrypt = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    unsigned char decryptedText1[MAX_TEXT_LENGTH + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH];
    unsigned char decryptedText2[MAX_TEXT_LENGTH + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH];
    int decryptedText1_len;
    int decryptedText2_len;
    memset(decryptedText1, 0, sizeof(decryptedText1));

    // Extract the IV from the concatenated message 2
    memcpy(iv, concatenatedMessage1, EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH);

    // Set the IV for the decryption operation
    if (EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx_decrypt, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, skey, iv) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error setting decryption IV\n");
    exit(1);
    }

    // Decrypt the ciphertext
    if (EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx_decrypt, decryptedText1, &decryptedText1_len, concatenatedMessage1 + EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH, concatenatedMessageLength1 - EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error decrypting data\n");
    exit(1);
    }

    // Finalize the decryption
    int final_len1;
    if (EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx_decrypt, decryptedText1 + decryptedText1_len, &final_len1) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error finalizing decryption\n");
    exit(1);
    }
    decryptedText1_len += final_len1;
    
    // Print the decrypted plaintext
    printf("Decrypted Text: %.*s\n", decryptedText1_len, decryptedText1);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx_decrypt);



    EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx_decrypt2 = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    // Initialize the encryption/decryption context
    if (EVP_CipherInit_ex(ctx_decrypt2, cipher, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error initializing the cipher context\n");
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx_decrypt2);
    return;
    }

    // Extract the IV from the concatenated message 1
    memcpy(iv, concatenatedMessage2, EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH);

    // Set the IV for the decryption operation
    if (EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx_decrypt2, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, decryptedText2, iv) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error setting decryption IV\n");
    exit(1);
    }

    // Decrypt the ciphertext
    if (EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx_decrypt2, decryptedText2, &decryptedText2_len, concatenatedMessage2 + EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH, concatenatedMessageLength2 - EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error decrypting data\n");
    exit(1);
    }

    // Finalize the decryption
    int final_len2;
    if (EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx_decrypt2, decryptedText2 + decryptedText2_len, &final_len2) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error finalizing decryption\n");
    exit(1);
    }
    decryptedText2_len += final_len2;

    // Print the decrypted plaintext
    printf("Decrypted Text: %.*s\n", decryptedText2_len, decryptedText2);

    // Check if the decrypted message matches the expected message
    const unsigned char* expectedMessage2 = (const unsigned char*)"Verification Message SessionKey";
    if (memcmp(decryptedText2, expectedMessage2, decryptedText2_len) == 0) {
    printf("Message verified\n");
    const unsigned char* DoneMessage = (const unsigned char*)"Bob Hello Done";
    ssize_t sent = send(sock, DoneMessage, strlen((const char*)DoneMessage), MSG_NOSIGNAL);
    if (sent < 0) {
        perror("[-]Error sending done message");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Done message sent\n");
    } else {
    printf("Message unverified\n");
    }
    bzero(buffer, 1024);
```

I am expecting it to be decrypted normally as i have done using the same snippet previously in the code and it was working fine. The only difference is that i have previously encrypted and decrypted a verification message only whereas this time it is an array. I am having error in finalizing decryption particularly in this line

```
    // Finalize the decryption
    int final_len1;
    if (EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx_decrypt, decryptedText1 + decryptedText1_len, &final_len1) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error finalizing decryption\n");
    exit(1);
    }
```

While debugging i also found that decrypted text length is 32 bytes. However, decryptedText1 still has 48 bytes. Kindly help me and tell me if i am doing something wrong. Stuck on this point for 2 weeks now.

Comment: Why? Why not just use SSL/TLS? It avoids your key distribution problem completely, among many other virtues.

Comment: Actually i am working on a group key agreement protocol. This is an intermediate step in the protocol

Comment: Moreover, i am following the concept of TLS in a more refined manner excluding all the overheads